# with wsl2, why do permissions revert back

Tags: linux, debian, wsl2

so i am having issues that are caused by the `/tmp` directory.

i have created `/etc/fstab` with the following:

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs mode=0755,uid=0,gid=0,size=48M 0 0
```

when i reboot wsl, i get the same issues.  what alleviates these is when i do either of the following:

`mount -t tmpfs none /tmp`
or
`sudo chmod 1777 /tmp`

now, i've tried to drop the `mount` command in `/root/.bashrc` -- it doesn't work.

i've also tried to drop the `chmod` command in `.bashrc` -- it doesn't work.

that's ok, but why are the permissions on `/tmp` reverting after i've already set them??

they keep going back to `drwxr-xr-x`

Answer (score 1):

ok so the issue was resolved by setting `/etc/fstab` with a `mode=1777`

so, i suppose that `fstab` either comes after `.bashrc` or that it supersedes it...